# -nan Error when trying to return the index of a class object

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class

So in my intro to CS class, we're learning about classes and I'm having a lot of trouble right now.

This is project 2 part 2:

https://github.com/CSCI1300-StartingComputing/CSCI1300-Spring2022/blob/main/project/project2/project2pt2.md#question0

project 2 part 1 (part 2 builds on a lot of this stuff:https://github.com/CSCI1300-StartingComputing/CSCI1300-Spring2022/blob/main/project/project2/project2pt1.md#question4

I am specifically on number 6 for part 2.

I believe the problem lies in the below snippet of code:

```
while (k < numbMovies){temp = movies[k].getTitle(); //store movie title into temp arr

//convert temp to lowercase for case insensitivity
while (b < temp.length()){temp[b] = tolower(temp[b]);
b++;
}

//if the title we're searching is found in the movies array
if (temp == title)
{
movieIdx = k; //the kth movie will be our match, so save k as our index
numMatches++; //increment number of matches. if the title is found, this should be one at most

}
k++;
}
```

---

There is an issue somewhere with the line temp = movies[k].getTitle();, I think.

What this line is supposed to do is reference an array from the Movie class developed in part 1, store a title found at 'k' from the movies array into a string so that I can compare it to the string being passed into the function (this comparison is done in the line containing if(temp == title).

I then wish to save the value of k when temp == title as movieIdx, so that this can be used further in this function.

I think that the problem is with my referencing of the movies[] array, but I'm not sure what it might be.

Since there are a lot of things going on in this project, I'd be happy to send my files over to anyone who'd be willing to take a look.

Thanks in advance.

FURTHER CONTEXT:
I was attempting to test edge cases by returning 'movieIdx' immediately after setting movieIdx = k, just to see what was going wrong. Example of what I mean:

```
{
movieIdx = k; //the kth movie will be our match, so save k as our index
numMatches++; //increment number of matches. if the title is found, this should be one at most
return movieIdx;
}
```

-nan was returned consistently, although if I returned k outside of the first while loop (that contains the other while loops), I'd get the value that was expected (50, in this case, which equals numbMovies). If I returned movieIdx outside of the loop, I got 0.

This told me that there was some issue with the condition if(temp == title). I then did a test where I replaced 'temp' with a hardcoded value that I knew would be passed, "the prestige".

Doing this returned the expected value. I then knew that there must be some issue with 'temp' itself, and I have assumed that the issue therein would probably have to do with how I'm referencing the movies[] array.

Comment: I strongly recommend rewriting this question to contain a [mre] (MRE). Not only will you know for certain that the mistake is in the provided code, odds are very good that you'll spot and fix the mistake while constructing the MRE.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.